# Biblioteca de animação c#

Tags: c#, animação

Em c# existe algum tipo de biblioteca parecida com jquery no sentido de fazer animações efeitos com elementos do formulário como fazer um texto de mover de um lado para outro e etc?

Comment: Para uma aplicação web ou desktop?

Comment: desktop windows application

Comment: Existe para .NET, se chama [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130(v=vs.110).aspx) (WPF).

Comment: parece ser bem interessante @Renan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silvio, o [Windows Presentation Foundation - WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) citado pelo @renan é a evolução das aplicações WinForms.

**XAML**

Ele é baseado em uma padrão **XAML**(Pronunciado como zammel (som em português de ZÊMEL)).
O XAML significa `_eXtensible Application Markup Language_` serve para estruturar as "janelas/forms" do WPF, são controles bem ricos em propriedades e podem ser facilmente extendidos por outro, dando assim uma grande maleabilidade a aplicação.

Dentro dos contextos de `WPF` e usando de sua poderosa extensibilidade, você consegue agregas muito efeitos a sua aplicação, criar botões redondos, animações, fundos dinâmicos, etc...

O WPF possui também um "irmão" para a WEB que é o `SilverLight`.

Compensa muito o estudo, você consegue uma boa base através do link acima...
Outros lugares que ajudaram seu estudo são esses:

[WPFTutotial](http://wpftutorial.net/)

[Blog do PauloQuicoli](http://quicoli.wordpress.com/)

Comment: Onde eu vivo todo mundo pronuncia XAML como "shíz-á-ême-éle" mesmo. De resto +1.

Comment: @Renan: a pronúncia vem do inglês... se você assistir qualquer vídeo sobre XAML em inglês vai ver que o tchicotti tem razão. Note que *razão != certo*... a forma que você indicou é igualmente válida.

Comment: Neste momento o SilverLight tem vida por mais 7 anos... até 2021.

Comment: @Renan é que assim nós brasileiros muitas vezes temos o costuma de soletrar aquilo que não sabemos a pronuncia corretamente. Exemplos clássicos: C# do C SHARP - Quando não se conhecia a pronuncia, costuma-se chamar de "C joguinho da velha" ou "C sustenido", até mesmo ja ouvi o "C lá da microsoft"...
Nâo está errado soletrar, assim como não está errado a pronuncia como o MiguelAngelo disse

Comment: *offtopic*: no caso do C#, hoje ouço todos falando "se sharpi"... é uma mistura, pois em inglês seria "si sharp". Mas eu não sou nenhum purista, acabo falando a versão aportuguesada também! =D

Comment: off: Eu tbm sou assim, depende do contexto da conversa, quando estou falando mta coisa em ingles na mesma sentença eu falo o ingles corretinho, se não, eu falo o portugues, ou então qdo não me entendem falando o ingles, tipo ("ah altera o 'eiti em el do si sharp" ai respondem: "o q?" e eu digo "HTML(aga te eme ele) do C# (se sharpi)")